# PHP check if array contains any key other than some whitelisted

Tags: php, arrays, get, whitelist

I would like to check all keys of a global GET array and do something, if it contains keys, other than some whitelisted ones from an array.

Let's say the current url is:

```
.../index.php?randomekey1=valueX&randomkey2=valueY&acceptedkey1=valueZ&randomkey3=valueA&acceptedkey2=valueB
```

Just for better visualization:
These GET parameters are all available in the global GET variable which looks something like this:

```
$GET = array(
    "randomekey1" => "valueX",
    "randomkey2" => "valueY",
    "acceptedkey1" => "valueZ",
    "randomkey3" => "valueA",
    "acceptedkey2" => "valueB"
);
```

The keys I accept and want to let pass, I put into an array too:

```
$whitelist = array(
    "acceptedkey1",
    "acceptedkey2",
    "acceptedkey3",
);
```

Now I want to check whether $GET contains any key other than the whitelisted. So in the URL example from above it should return "true", because there are keys in the $GET array which aren't in the whitelist.

Not only the existence of such an unknown (none whitelisted) key should trigger a true, but please also its emptyness!

---

Another example would be the following url:

```
.../index.php?acceptedkey1=valueZ&acceptedkey3=valueB
```

This should return false, because no other key other than the ones in the whitelist were found.

Unfortunately I was not able to find any modification of the in_array function or array_search which would fit these requirements, because as far as I know these functions are only looking for something specific, whereas in my requirements I am also looking for something specific (the whitelist keys), but at the same tme I have to check if some unknown keys exist.

Thank you.

Comment: What do you mean by "Not only the existence of such an unknown (none whitelisted) key should trigger a true, but please also its emptyness"?

Comment: I'm sorry, is it ```array_key_exists``` function what you have tried? Remember that if you want to check in $GET, it is an associative array (key->value) which means you need to specifically look for the key (in your case) to verify if your whitelisted regular array elements exists.

Comment: Also see [array_diff()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php) or [array_diff_assoc()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff-assoc.php).

Comment: Do you want to remove any key (and values) that is not whitelisted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you want to determine whether an array contains keys that don't exist in a whitelist.
One way to find the difference between arrays is to use [`array_diff()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php):

> **array_diff ( array $array1 , array $array2 [, array $... ] ) : array**
>   Returns an array containing all the entries from `array1` that are not present in any of the other arrays.

So, it can be used to return all keys from the URL that are not present in the whitelist:

```
$extrasExist = !empty( array_diff( array_keys($GET), $whitelist ) );
var_dump($extrasExist);
```

Here's a demonstration:

```php
$get1 = array(
    "randomekey1" => "valueX",
    "randomkey2" => "valueY",
    "acceptedkey1" => "valueZ",
    "randomkey3" => "valueA",
    "acceptedkey2" => "valueB"
);

$get2 = array(
    "acceptedkey1" => "valueZ",
    "acceptedkey2" => "valueB"
);

$whitelist = array(
    "acceptedkey1",
    "acceptedkey2",
    "acceptedkey3"
);

$extrasExist = !empty(array_diff(array_keys($get1),$whitelist));
var_dump($extrasExist);

$extrasExist = !empty(array_diff(array_keys($get2),$whitelist));
var_dump($extrasExist);
```

> bool(true)
>   bool(false)

Comment: @DanielM bare in mind that this approach is suboptimal. Probably not a big deal for small arrays. But if you had big arrays it would be wiser to end the check as soon as you find first item that is not on the whitelist. The proposed approach will walk through entire array even if it is not at all necesary...

Answer (score 1):

Everything in PHP doesn't have to be all "lets find function that does exactly what I'm looking for". Just do a simple foreach loop, which can accomplish what you're looking for:

```
function clear_filter() {
    $whitelist = array( "project", "table_name", "filterDates", );
    foreach ($_GET as $gkey => $gval) {
        if (!in_array($gkey, $whitelist)) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

You can also write it more simply, with one foreach loop like below:

```
function isValid() {
    // Copy the array
    $temp = $_GET;

    // Loop through the array, and remove any whitelisted elements
    foreach ($whitelist as $wkey) {
        unset($temp[$wkey]);
    }
    // If count($temp) > 0, there are non whitelisted entries in the array.
    return count($temp) === 0;
}
```

Comment: "Everything in PHP doesn't have to be all "lets find function that does exactly what I'm looking for". I know, that's why I said I found no fitting **modification** of these functions. Anyway, your first suggestion doesn't work for me at all. It returns true no matter if non whitelisted keys are present or not. And the second one works kind of, but reversed. It gives me a 1 when only whitelisted are found, and gives nothing if also non-whitelisted are found. I could somehow work with the second one. So thanks.

Comment: @DanielM The first function I accidentally put `if ($wkey != $wkey)`, which broke the function. Both of these functions though, are going to be a lot more efficient than the `array_diff`, as you don't need to allocate more arrays. I'd highly recommend using one of the above solutions if you care at all about performance.

Comment: can't get it to work. It is giving me false all the time.


`function clear_filter() {
 
 $whitelist = array(
  "project",
  "table_name",
  "filterDates",
 ); 
 
 
    foreach ($_GET as $gkey => $gval) {
        foreach ($whitelist as $wkey) {
            if ($gkey != $wkey) {
                return 'false';
            }
        }
    }
    return 'true';
} 
 
echo clear_filter();`

Comment: @DanielM See my updated first function. When doing a `var_dump()` I realized it was comparing every key, and as soon as the first one didn't match, it would return. This would indeed always fail unless both `$whitelist`, and `$array` were exactly one item. Using `in_array()` now fixes this.

Comment: Also avoid returning strings of `'true'` or `'false'`. If you want to see the boolean result, use `var_dump(clear_filter())`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following function.

```
$check = checkWhitliest( $_GET, $whitelist ) );
var_dump ($check );
```

You can call the above function as

```
function checkWhitliest( $array, $whitelist ) {

    $allKeys = array_keys ( $array); //Get all Keys from the array.
    $diff = array_diff( $allKeys, $whitelist); //Get the values which are not in whitelist.
    if( count ( $diff ) > 0 ) {     //If the count is greater than 0, then there are certain extra kesy in $_GET
        return true;
    }
    return false;

}
```

Comment: You could simply write `return count($diff) > 0;`

Answer (score 0):

There are only two techniques that I would recommend for this task and both make key comparisons for performance reasons.  Using `array_diff()` or `in_array()` will always be slower than `array_diff_key()` and `isset()`, respectively, because of how PHP treats arrays as hash maps.

If you don't mind iterating the entire `$GET` array (because its data is relatively small), then you can concisely flip the whitelist array and check for any key differences.

```
var_export(
    (bool)array_diff_key($GET, array_flip($whitelist))
);
```

If performance is more important than code brevity, then you should craft a technique that uses a conditional `break` or `return` as soon as a non-whitelisted key is encountered -- this avoids doing pointless iterations after the outcome is decided.

```
$hasNotWhitelisted = false;
$lookup = array_flip($whitelist);
foreach ($GET as $key => $value) {
    if (isset($lookup[$key])) {
        $hasNotWhitelisted = true;
        break;
    }
}
var_export($hasNotWhitelisted);
```

Or

```
function hasNotWhitelisted($array, $whitelist): bool {
    $lookup = array_flip($whitelist);
    foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
        if (isset($lookup[$key])) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
var_export(hasNotWhitelisted($GET, $whitelist));
```

All of the above techniques deliver a `true` result for the sample data.  [Demo of all three snippets.](https://3v4l.org/JQXUD)